# SwiftUI: How can I change inline NavigationBar color when PopupView appears?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I want to change inline NavigationBar color when PopupView appears.

```swift
struct TestView3: View {
    @State private var showPopup: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text("text \(i)")
                    }
                }
                
                BackgroundOverlayView {
                    BasePopupView(titleText: nil, primaryText: "dd", secondaryText: nil, primaryButtonTitle: "aa", primaryButtonAction: {
                        self.showPopup = false
                    }, secondaryButtonTitle: nil, secondaryButtonAction: nil)
                }
                .hidden(!showPopup)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

It's not what I want like this. ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq5S1.png

This is what I want to do. - >
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2j2W.png

So, I added the following code and it appears as I want but there's one problem because NavigationBar was clear together. The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oToY.png

```
init() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
}
```

```swift
struct TestView3: View {
    @State private var showPopup: Bool = true
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text("text \(i)")
                    }
                }
                
                BackgroundOverlayView {
                    BasePopupView(titleText: nil, primaryText: "dd", secondaryText: nil, primaryButtonTitle: "aa", primaryButtonAction: {
                        self.showPopup = false
                    }, secondaryButtonTitle: nil, secondaryButtonAction: nil)
                }
                .hidden(!showPopup)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct BackgroundOverlayView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            content()
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color(white: 0/255, opacity: 0.2))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

How can I change navigation bar color overlay together when popupview appears and not to be completely clear?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change just one specific Navigation bar in a view, but there is a little hacky/trick you can do:

You've already added these lines:

```
   UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
   UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

And you mentioned the Navigation Bar was completely clear and your content could be seen through where your Navigation Bar is/should be, to fix this, simply add padding to your `ScrollView`, like so:

```
ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("text \(i)")
            }
        }.padding(.top)
```

This stops your content from going "through" your Navigation bar.